Resampling techniques to obtain uniform random variables.
Suppose we have $n$ iid samples $X_i$ from a distribution, say a triangular distribution symmetric about the origin, with support $[-h,h]$, $h>0$ (denote this density $f(x)$). I would like to resample them, such that the subsample obtained has iid uniform distributions on $[-1,1]$ (density $.5I_{[-1,1]}(x)$). Other similar questions have been posted, suggesting that the resampling should be the following: in my subsample I will include $X_i$ w.p. $.5/f(X_i)$ if $X_i\in[-1,1]$, otherwise not.
At least for the case that $h\geq 1$ I can show that given that a distribution has been sampled, in the new subsample it will be distributed as uniform on $[-1,1]$ as intended. But what if $h<1$? Is it still possible to do this? The support seems in the way and resampling is not sufficient in my opinion.
Going back to the case $h\geq 1$, I have an issue with computing the average size of this subsample. It seems to me that, conditionally on the sample, the random size of the subsample is given by $\sum_{i=1}^n Ber(.5I_{[-1,1]}(X_i)/f(X_i))$. Now, exploiting the law of total expectation, I obtain (unconditional) expected size of the subsample to be $n$, because each $Ber(.5I_{[-1,1]}(X_i)/f(X_i))$ has conditional expectation $.5I_{[-1,1]}(X_i)/f(X_i)$ and then taking expectation wrt $X_i$ yields $\int_{-1}^1.5dx=1$. This cannot be right, is my resampling parameter wrong or did I model incorrectly the random size of the subsample?
Thanks for any help.
EDIT. I think I can fix the issue with the expectation by including a suitable constant in the acceptance probability. However, I still do not see how this can be done with $h<1$.

Actually by multiplying your sample by a suitable constant, which is $1/h$, then you will always scale them back to the support $[-1, 1]$ while preserving the triangular distribution.

If your algorithm can do "accept with probability $p$" then it effectively already has a random number generator.

Your triangular distribution has density $f_X(x)=\dfrac{h-|x|}{h^2}\mathbb I_{[|x|\le h]}$.
There are various approaches. The simplest is:

If $h>1$, you could resample by accepting each $x_i$ with probability $\dfrac{h-|x_i|}{h-1}\mathbb I_{[|x_i|\le 1]}$

Note that the probability of acceptance would in $[0,1]$, which does always not seem to be the case with your suggestion.  It does not work with $0 \le h\le 1$ as you would not accept any values.  Overall, it gives a probability of acceptance of $\frac{2(h-1)}{h^2}$ which achieves its maximum value of $\frac12$ when $h=2$.  So this suggests an alternative approach by rescaling your observations to $\frac{2x_i}{h}$ and then resampling, which would also work for small $0<h\ll 1$ and be more efficient for $h \gg 2$:

Accept $\dfrac{2x_i}{h}$ with probability $2\left(1-|\frac{x_i}{h}|\right)\mathbb I_{\left[|x_i|\le \frac h2\right]}$

